# Spark optimizer giving wrong output

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
CODE HERE...   
 def getMeasure = udf((next: String) =>{
          if(next.equals("[ArStart]")){"Reboot"}
          else if(next.equals("[MONITOR]")){"Reload"}
          else{"Others"}
        })
    val systemWindow = Window.partitionBy($"company", $"location", $"systemname").orderBy($"timestamp",$"rn")

val tmp_dev_msg_1 = ds_state_2.where($"replaced_device_message".isNotNull)
val tmp_dev_msg_2 = tmp_dev_msg_1
        .withColumn("measure", getMeasure(lead($"replaced_device_message", 1).over(systemWindow)))
val test = tmp_dev_msg_2
        .select($"timestamp", $"rn", $"measure")
val ds_measure_1 = ds_state_2.join(test, Seq("timestamp" , "rn"), "leftouter")

MORE CODE HERE
```

This code is working perfectly without the join statement. Printing the test dataset shows me only entries where replaced_device_message is not null.

When I execute with the join statement I get a nullpointer exception for the function getMeasure. But this should not be possible since I am looking at `tmp_dev_msg1($"replaced_device_message")` which can not contain any null values.

EDIT: The wrong behaviour shows for entries where the timestamp is not unique. But from my understanding this should not be a problem since I also have a row_number -> rn which is unique

> Error message: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user
>   defined function(anonfun$getMeasure$1$1: (string) => string)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)   at
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   Stability$$anonfun$getMeasure$1$1.apply(Stability.scala:165)  at
>   Stability$$anonfun$getMeasure$1$1.apply(Stability.scala:164)

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest to use filter instead of where. `val tmp_dev_msg_1 = ds_state_2.filter($"replaced_device_message".isNotNull)`. As my understanding where should go with select or other methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885979/difference-between-filter-and-where-in-scala-spark-sql
where and filter should work the same.  I changed the question. Not the show was making my code work but getting rid of the join statement